# What is the chances that Gutz the Blacksmith's event will be succesful?

Tags: dokapon-kingdom

In Dokapon Kingdom for the Wii and PS2, Gutz the Blacksmith has a chance to make a new piece of equipment for the player if they pay a certain amount of gold. This can either succeed, giving the player a new piece of equipment, usually stronger than their current one, or fail, causing the player to lose out on all the gold they spent. My question is what are the chances behind it? As in, what percentage of the time will it succeed?

I have looked at the wiki page, which isn't really helpful:

> In Dokapon Kingdom, he is a Special Event NPC. He will offer the player to build them a new piece of equipment for a certain amount of gold. If the player gives the gold, Gutz can either fail or succeed at crafting the equipment.